# HTML email <tr> tag border formatting issue

Tags: html, perl, outlook, html-email

I am trying to format the table to have rows separated by lines.Even tried using inline styles but nothing worked. Am I missing anything here?

Expected output : [image]

Output I am getting : [image]

Here is the perl code that I am using to generate the HTML for the email :

```
my $section_html = '';
$section_html.=qq(<table><tr style="border : 1px solid black;"><td>Hello1</td><td>Hello2</td></tr><tr style="border : 1px solid black;"><td>Hello3</td><td>Hello4</td></tr></table>);

my $email_html = <<EOF;
<html><head><style type="text/css">
body, td, th, strong { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; }


table {
    border:none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align:center;
}

table td {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

table th {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

table td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
    text-align:left;
}

table  td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

table tr{
border-top : 1px solid #000;
}

table tr{
border-top : 1px solid black;
}


</style></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<span style="font-size: 20px">Report Header</span>$section_html</body></html>
EOF

# Write to file
open(FILE, ">/var/weekly_report/"."report"."_"."testing".".html") or die "Unable to open file for writing: $!\n";
print FILE $email_html;
close(FILE);


# Email weekly report
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    To         => 'XXXX@somedomain.com',
    Subject => 'Report subject',
    Type    => 'text/html',
    Data    => $email_html);


    $msg->send();
```

Comment: If you define `border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;` for the `table` element, you will get what you want and you can drop all border styles from `td`, `th` and `tr`.

Comment: @FBergo Nope, did not work ... .changed removed all the other css and changed the table to " $section_html.=qq(<table style='border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;'><tr><td>Hello1</td><td>Hello2</td></tr><tr><td>Hello3</td><td>Hello4</td></tr></table>);"

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-collapse

Comment: Generated HTML Renders correctly on the browser, there is only a problem while rendering the HTML via outlook

Comment: Oh, take a look at this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462203/outlook-client-not-properly-rendering-table-borders (outlook's HTML rendering has its quirks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some email clients (and maybe browsers) don't allow us to directly style the `<tr>` tag. It's also safer to avoid relying on `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo selectors, as they are [not well supported in email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/first-child/).

However you we can achieve your desired effect by styling the `<table>` and `<td>` tags:

```
table {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
table td,
table th {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

---

You can also have absolute control by inlining all CSS, which is still a good idea in HTML email.

Answer (score 1):

This is going old school. Try this method as well. The difference from Ted's answer is, you have the whole table the same color and in his answer you can choose the border color for different `td's` or `th's`.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="#000000">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" bgcolor="#ffffff">Hello1</td>
      <td width="50%" bgcolor="#ffffff">Hello1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff">Hello1</td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff">Hello1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```